# div won't go behind nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an h3 inside it (that goes up on user hover) and a background image, and my nav bar has a z-index of 1, so why is this div, which is the name of a project i worked on, in front? the background image is behind the nav bar, but the project name div is in front. pic attached of the problem.

[image: the h3 is in front of the nav bar instead of behind it]

Here is my html structure and CSS:

```css
/* this is the css relevant to the project title "bbc project" */

.text {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 90%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

.text:hover {
    height: 110px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.text h3 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
}

/* this is the css relevant to the nav bar. */
nav {
        background-color: #644124;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 20px;
}
nav ul {
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        justify-content: center;
}
nav ul li a {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
        padding: 0 15px;
        color: #FDEBC4;
        transition: 0.2s;
        text-decoration: none;

}
nav ul li a:hover {
        transition: 0.2s;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div>
<div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about-me">about me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact me">contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="text">
        <h3 class="project-name">bbc project</h3> 
        <div class="content">
            <p> a bbc website clone to demonstrate my skills </p>
        </div>
    
        <a class="button" href="bbc clone.html" target="_bank"> view project</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

I want the project name to be behind the nav bar with the background image.

Comment: You'll have to show us your html structure - most likely it's because your div is in a different [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) to your nav bar

Comment: Because `.text` has `z-index: 2;` maybe? But that's speculation - without HTML code and full CSS it's impossible to give a reliable answer...

Comment: I made your code a runnable snippet. You have HTML errors - I added the surrounding divs and the section tag. Weird that you would have the navigation in the same section as the content but you can correct your HTML if I interpreted that incorrectly. You have no background image anywhere only colors. Did you mean the colors?